# How to replace all characters in a String except certain character?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        //replace all char to 1 other then c and g
        String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        String answer = str.replaceAll("[^cg]+", "1");
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

- Current output: `1c1g1`
- Wanted output: `11c111g111111111111111111`

Comment: Remove `+` from your regex and use: `"[^cg]"`

Answer (score 2):

> Now here I am getting an output as 1c1g1, but what I want is 11c111g111111111111111111

Remove the `+`. That says "match one or more of the previous" but you're replacing that series of matching characters with **one** `1`.

So:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){
        //replace all char to 1 other then c and g
        String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        String answer = str.replaceAll("[^cg]", "1");
        // No + here ------------------------^
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

[Live Copy](https://ideone.com/2a7EtC)

Comment: But what if there are more c and g present in the string, I just took an example. Its not like the c and g will appear only once.

Comment: @suchit - What if they do? The `[^cg]` means "a single character that isn't a c or a g". `replaceAll` replaces all occurrences that match the expression. It doesn't matter how often `c` or `g` appears in the string, they'll always be skipped, since they don't match `[^cg]`. For instance, if you make your starting string `"abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg"`, the result of the above is `"11c111g11c111g11c111g11c111g"`: https://ideone.com/OzUR0H

Comment: Yes I tested. Thanks